# Setting active tab current tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have three tabs that i'm setting active, due to a certain functionality, the last active tab might not be the one the user on. So at the end of this 3 line code i'm trying to set active the tab that the user is on:

```
tabPanel.setActiveTab(1);
  tabPanel.setActiveTab(2);
  tabPanel.setActiveTab(0);
```

I want to set the current tab the tab that the user is on, (the active tab).
Any help on this?

Comment: Can you explain it again? question is unclear

Comment: Can you explain what do you want exactly? 
Active tab is the one which on which user is currently on. What do you want to set? Framework automatically sets the value for active tab.

Comment: @Style i edit the question

Comment: @AbdulRehmanYawarKhan i edit the question

Comment: Maybe you meant enabled? You want set all 3 tabs enabled and set first one active?

Comment: @mikeb I am not able to understand you question properly, but trust me on this, once you call tabPanel.setActiveTab(xyz); then the current active tab will be the one on 'xyz' index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var currentTab = tabPanel.getActiveTab();

tabPanel.setActiveTab(0);
tabPanel.setActiveTab(1);
tabPanel.setActiveTab(2);

tabPanel.setActiveTab(currentTab);
```